# What does nested JSON array look like in mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, json, nested

I have a manually constructed json file that's something like this:

```
{
  "Thing": [
   {
      "post": "blah",
      "comments": [
          {
             "text": "blahblah"
          },
          {
             "text": "blahblahblah"
          }
       ]
   }
}
```

I'm trying to do a JSON -> mySQL table with PHP.

My understanding of a mySQL table is that "Thing" would be the title of the table; "post" and "comments" would be column headers. Please correct me if any of this is wrong.

So I'm confused about the nested array of objects that have "text" and how that would supposedly 'look' in a table format, and also how I'm supposed to handle nested values in json strings when trying to populate a mySQL table.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As for populating the table, you'd use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an association:

first table is:

```
  Posts
  id title text
```

second table is:

```
 Comments
 id post_id text
```

When you will look for your comments you will simply call

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = 'yourpostid'
```

For your json, please have a look on json_decode and json_encode. It will be simplier.